# The image you are requesting does not exist?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

Fill in the table below, to get the final answer that consists of 2 words.

[image: table]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The two words we are looking for are:

> MISLEADING IMAGES

First I noticed that

> The title of the question seems to refer to imgur image links. Substituting the ***** in link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/****.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXCX0.png) with the five character strings in the table, you'll land on an (apparently) non existing pages, each with the note "The image you are requesting does not exist". BUT they're not the standard "404 error" pages of imgur site: each "fake page" is slightly different.

Because:

> **[RXCX0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXCX0.png)** leads to a page where the words are **horizontally spaced**, more than the standard

> **[CmjLw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmjLw.png)** leads to a page where the words are **vertically spaced**, more than the standard

> **[ZgmPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgmPN.png)** leads to a page where the words are **on the top** of the page

> **[u1y88](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1y88.png)** leads to a page where the words are **on the right** side of the page

> **[X8kRy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8kRy.png)** leads to a page where the words are **rotated 90°** clockwise

These is clearly related with red-orange-yellow dots in the first column of the table.

Filling the table with

> '1' or '0' in each column, if each image on the left has one of the 5 characteristic (horizontally/vertically spaced, on the top, on the right, rotated), we obtain a list of binary numbers, that can be easily converted to decimal and then to alphabet letters.

For example:

> the image in the first blank line is *vertically spaced*, *rotated clockwise* and *on the top* -> 0-1-1-0-1

> [image: filled grid]

PS:

> In considering if an image is spaced horizontally ol vertically, you must consider if it is also rotated! (So an "horizontally spaced" image rotated clockwise appears "vertically spaced")

Comment: Solving as a simple substitution gives rot13(`haoernxvat vzntrf`). Recovering the substitution key and comparing it to a well-known substitution suggests that the first two columns in the grid have been swapped.

Comment: A more likely solution is rot13(`zvfyrnqvat vzntrf`). I can't tell whether the apparent mistakes are in the puzzle's setting or in your partial solution.

Comment: @codewarrior0: ok, I've understood what the intended solution is, I'm going to update my answer (ps: there aren't errors in the puzzle's setting, it's a question of interpreting correctely the images on the left)